# How do I install a program from a cd?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install my Evermore Integrate Office 2007 from my cd.  Followed the instructions exactly, but hit different problems. Previously I installed it like that on an Acer Aspire One Netbook.

> Linux Installation:
>   Method One: Log on as root and insert the CD installation disk in the CD or DVD ROM drive, run  from the EIOffice CD and the EIOffice Install Wizard will begin. Follow the On-Screen install procedure.

Click on setup and I get this error;

```
Invalid url: '/media/chris/EIO2007/Linux/setup' given, exiting
No ':' in the uri
```

> Method Two: Log on as root and Insert the CD installation disk in the CD or DVD ROM drive. Run the terminal window and input "cd /mnt/cdrom/Linux", press Enter and then input "./setup", the EIOffice Install Wizard will begin. Follow the On-Screen install procedure.

Sudo'd into root.
In my case `~#: cd /media/chris/EIO2007/Linux`.  Command "setup" gets error command not found, `./setup` gets error Permission denied.

Tried `cd /media/chris/EIO2007`
then  `cp /media/chris/EIO2007/Linux /usr/EIO2007`
gets cp: omitting directory /media/chris/EIO207/Linux'  (read-only disc?)

chmod 1777 not working as expected since it is a read-only disc.

I can read all the files in command line after
`cd /media/chris/EIO2007/Linux` and
`ls -l`
as I see them in the File Manager, so I don't understand the error in the first method.

Thought of `sudo apt install`, but there is no identifiable file name.  The `/Linux/assocaiate` (sic) folder has three directories; Fedora, Impi and Suse.
Oh yes, there is a "dispose.jar" file but I do not understand/fear to try it without at least some knowledge of it.

Wit's end.  Any ideas welcome, thanks.

Comment: 'chmod 1777 not working' - did you mean 0777? The best command to give executable permission is `chmod +x FILES'. Anyway, it's not gonna work in a read-only path.

Comment: Another question -- why are you using a proprietary (according to my knowledge) office package when you have LibreOffice?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /media/chris/EIO2007/Linux/setup` and `grep -Fe /media/chris/EIO2007 /proc/mounts`?

Comment: This is 10 year old software. Is it still supported on current linux distributions? Libreoffice is probably a better alternative. It is stable as long as you work in the native formats and export to MSO when needed.

Comment: David, Output to the first question is this; -r-------- 1 chris chris 23333 Oct 19  2006 /media/chris/EIO2007/Linux/setup.  Output to the grep is/dev/sr0 /media/chris/EIO2007 iso9660 ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 0 0.

Comment: Nandakumar, I am newly from Windows and stumbled on it then.  It was also a quarter of the price of MS Office.  I had a mind then to convert to Linux, but life interfered.  It auto-updates, uses one file format for spreadsheet, word processor and presentation apps.  You can see all three in the same window, data is updated interactively as you go.  You can build links to data on the HDD without those files in memory.  Spreadsheet can zoom anything from 1 thru 400%.  Very good for fine design.  Paid for it, can just as well use it.

Comment: The last I saw anything near like this was the Canadian Gold Disk Office on the Amiga A500.  It can open/read MSO files AND save to all MS Formats.  I sincerely doubt LibreOffice can beat this, but that is my opinion.  But I think you have to blame the Amiga for it.  Their  philosophy was intuitive computing.  Do it as you think, true transparency.  Download the 30 day trial form www.yozosoft.com and see for yourself.      I did not expect the chmod to work, just did it as a test, pot luck to find whatever came and to prove that I did all I could before asking a dumb question.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest.  Oh, I do NOT have any connection to Yozosoft.  It is just plain very b . . . . .  good.

Comment: Bruni,  This thing updates every time you open it.  I was surprised when I saw other Linux users talking about Yozosoft 2015!  So, yes, I think it will still be supported.  With Yozo you can convert EIO<>MSO, but that's the long way.  You can simply open and save  from the window.  Any Format.

Comment: @Nandakumar, I answered your posts, but am still learning the site protocols.

Comment: @Bruni,  I answered your post, but still learning site protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Execution permission issue always happens in GNU/Linux when you try to install something from CD-ROM. This is probably because the CD-ROM filesystem is not designed to handle Unix execution permissions.

The best thing you can do here is to copy the content of the disk to a local folder, give files appropriate permissions and run the setup.

If the problem with colon (:) exists because the setup program expects it, you can simply fake it by renaming the parent directory with a colon in it (I'm afraid I'm not sure about it -- it could have been an issue with Nautilus also; anyway, try).

Comment: I tried that as I said in the second paragraph under Method 2.  Ubuntu will NOT copy the file on disc to an internal folder.  If I have it correctly the parent cannot be renamed as it is on a read-only disc.  OK, ta, set me to thinking.  Maybe some other ideas to try.

Comment: @David, The output to the grep command gave me the idea on Nanda's comment about permissions.  Did cp /dev/sr0 /usr/Yozo.  Disc spun up flawlessly.  Opened up /usr/Yozo and there she was! sr0, but I can't open it.  OK, Properties, sure enough; 256.6MB.  Just about the right size for both Windows and Linux Files.

Comment: @Christo, please try other methods to copy the disc. You can create an ISO image of the disc using Brasero, open it with Archive Manager (not mounter), extract the files and do the permissions thing. Try that and let me know where it leads us to.

Comment: I did think of that, but I did not know about Brasero.  I incidentally tried to open the sr0 file in the file manager with several options, but no go.  In the same session I clicked on another file I had downloaded in /tmp/something.  No external disc near it, same (:) error.  Trying to find it again not successful.  Your interest much appreciated.  Will do.

Comment: @Christo, opening sr0 is not a solution. It is just a raw binary stream. you have to either mount it (which is what automatically happens when we 'open' a CD) or convert it to a useful format. Mere mounting has proved useless in your case, that's why I suggest the second choice: creating an ISO image of the disk with Brasero and trying to extract files from it. I'm happy to learn that you've got the idea and started working on it. Please let me know what happens.

Comment: Correct.  Downloaded Brasero to the internal HDD an lo and behold!      Invalid url: '/tmp/mozilla_mozillaUser0/brasero-3.12.0/configure' given, exiting
No ':' in the uri

Comment: Did you try copying all the content to a folder with ':' in its name (create something fake) and run from there?

Comment: Anyway, did other things, then tried saving /EIO2007/Linux to the internal HDD at /usr/Yozo/Linux and it worked.  All 233.36 MB.  Then `cd /Yozo/Linux, chmod 0774 setup`,  then `./setup` : Error : `
bash: ./setup: No such file or directory`.  For Brasero is this format correct? "brasero:".

Comment: You copied to /usr/Yozo/Linux and cd'd to /Yozo/Linux? Path incorrect?

Comment: I do not even need to test it.  Ubuntu does NOT allow incorrect paths.  I always have to enter the entire path from root right  down.  No assumptions.  These are just abbreviations to fit into this posting space.  Actually copy/pasted entire history from shell, but erased it.  cd into working directory is one lesson I picked up early on. Debugging line code all over again.

Comment: could you post the output of the `ls` command?

Comment: Sorry, head cold.

Comment: And again, how do you format these posts to look like something sensible?  Tab = carriage return?   root@hazzard:/home/chris# cd /usr/Yozo:
root@hazzard:/usr/Yozo:# ./setup
bash: ./setup: No such file or directory
root@hazzard:/usr/Yozo:# setup
setup: command not foundroot@hazzard:/usr/Yozo:# ls -l
total 40852
drwxrwxr-x 5 chris chris     4096 Oct 20  2006 assocaiate
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris      523 Oct 19  2006 config.eni
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris       75 Oct 19  2006 dispose.ini
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris   995107 Oct 19  2006 dispose.jar

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 2 chris chris     4096 Oct 20  2006 font
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris      521 Oct 19  2006 InstallInfo.ini
drwxrwxr-x 2 chris chris     4096 Oct 20  2006 instdata
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris 40526675 Oct 19  2006 Jre.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris     7155 Jul 26  2006 linkscript
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris      933 Oct 20  2006 README IMPI INSTALL.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris     2853 Oct 19  2006 Readme.txt
-rwxrwxr-- 1 chris chris    23333 Oct 19  2006 setup
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris   183656 Oct 19  2006 setup.bmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 chris chris    55135 Oct 19  2006 start.jpg
.../Yozo:#

Comment: Oh yes, the colon (:) bug persists no matter where the file is placed.  Latest, which is critical, is my downloaded KompoZer app

Comment: Your setup file has permissions `-rw-rw-r--`. Use the command `chmod +x setup` and run `./setup` again. If failed again, try to find the file format of setup. Is it a shell script? If so, you can try `sh setup`

Comment: Weird, but thank you.  Did as exactly as instructed on my old Linux Acer Aspire One Netbook and is installed, no change to these instructions.  Never even thought of questioning it.  Should have.  OK ,so this is really back to debugging line coding again.

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: Sorry, did other things - and got them right, ta!.  You're on the nail there, but now I have a libXext.so.6 file that is not found.  So it goes.  Saw some ideas on Stackoverflow and I have to create a symlink to /usr/lib64.  This is a common problem with many Google links on the SERP.  Also related to the fact that I want to install a 32-bit app on a 64-bit PC.  Learning as I go.  Will definitely let you know whatever happens.  Thank your for your sustained commitment so far.  Much appreciated.  Last thing, then I get to work again!